# Substitute a string in a strings array VBS

Tags: arrays, string, pointers, vbscript, char

I have an array of strings like this:

```
 strings = ("asd","zxc","qwe","ert")    

'strings(0) -> asd
'strings(1) -> zxc
'ecc.
```

How can substitute a string in it?

Example strings = ("ggg","zxc","qwe","ert")

I tried:  strings(0) = "ggg"

but it's not working

maybe I have to use set?

Also I don't want to always use static strings like "ggg", but also strings contained in a variable

Thank you

Comment: `strings(0) = "ggg"` is right.

Comment: @GSerg it would be if they had used `strings = Array("asd","zxc","qwe","ert")`. Also, "it's not working" isn’t very descriptive. What’s not working, was there an error?

Comment: I solved, the problem was that I was calling a sub with parentheses. So the strings Array parameter was not passed correctly